# jQuery update li class attribute href after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I'm using my Wordpress site and have a popup modal window that just presents some radio buttons (#input_1_1). When changing value of the radio button field an ajax call is run and performs a simple mySql table update. All goes well and I would like to perform a change of the text of the href I used to open the window in the first place.

Below is the javascript I got so far, but the second JQuery row from the bottom does not execute the change I want. Regardless of even just trying to change the simple target url.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#input_1_1").change(function(){
            jQuery("body").css("cursor", "wait");
            var commitmentID = jQuery("#gform_1 input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            jQuery('#popmake-710').popmake('close');
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type:'POST',
                data:'action=gf_submit_1_1&commitmentID=' + commitmentID,
                success:function(results)
                {
                    //Here is the problem I've been working on for too many hours/days now
                    jQuery("#et-secondary-nav > li.popmake-fast-select-commitment.current_commitment_text.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-563").attr('href',"http://www.TheSameUrlButILikeADifferentTextToIt.com");
                    //See line above
                    jQuery("body").css("cursor", "default");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is how the HTML for that part of the page looks like

```
        <div id="et-secondary-menu">
        <ul id="et-secondary-nav" class="menu">
            <li class="bp-menu bp-profile-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-152"></li>
            <li class="popmake-fast-select-commitment current_commitment_text menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-563" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <a href="http://www.myoriginalurlisjustfine.com/">
                    <i class="wp-svg-heart heart"></i>
                    THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I WANT TO HAVE CHANGED BY THE JQUERY AND IS THE TEXT PRESENTED IN THE SECONDARY WORDPRESS MENU
                </a>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you use

```
jQuery("#et-secondary-nav > li.popmake-fast-select-commitment.current_commitment_text.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-563")
```

and this will just select the li  which not has a href attr so you need to use (**> a**)

```
jQuery("#et-secondary-nav > li.popmake-fast-select-commitment.current_commitment_text.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-563 > a").attr('href',"http://www.TheSameUrlButILikeADifferentTextToIt.com");
```

Comment: Great. I got that I was targeting the wrong object. But even with this change there is no effect on the 'right' object. Since I don't know how to change the text I just tried to change the URL with no success. Secondly: How do I format the attr to keep the URL but change the text "THIS IS THE TEXT..."?

Comment: @JompaBoy  use .text()   ...  $(selector).text('THIS IS THE TEXT');

Comment: Perfect! Really appreciated you input! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#et-secondary-nav > li.popmake-fast-select-commitment.current_commitment_text.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-563").attr('href',"http://www.TheSameUrlButILikeADifferentTextToIt.com");
```

you are seleting the `li` here not `a`

change it to

```
jQuery("#et-secondary-nav > li.popmake-fast-select-commitment.current_commitment_text.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-563 > a").attr('href',"http://www.TheSameUrlButILikeADifferentTextToIt.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`jQuery("#et-secondary-nav > li.popmake-fast-select-commitment.current_commitment_text.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-563 a").attr('href',"http://www.TheSameUrlButILikeADifferentTextToIt.com");`

to change the href. As others pointed out, you weren't change the `<a>` but the `<li>`.

Check https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for reference on jQuery selectors.